# why my peerconnection don't generate ice candidate?

Tags: webrtc

i'm working with WebRTC.
In my peerconnection, i have added localdescription(offer) and remotedescription(answer).
but i can't see any ice generated.

```
RTCPeerConnection {localDescription: RTCSessionDescription, remoteDescription: RTCSessionDescription, signalingState: "have-local-offer", iceGatheringState: "new", iceConnectionState: "new", …}
```

They always stay in new state.
There are offer and answer inside.
Is anything i missed?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyPce.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a track via addTrack or created a datachannel? Otherwise there is nothing to negotiate and your offer will not contain any mediasection (the thing that starts with m=)

Comment: thanks bro, i found i forgot to addstream to my peerconnection